# Help installing fastCGI on linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd, fastcgi

I run the following:

```
$ cd /opt/mod_fastcgi-2.4.6
$ cp Makefile.AP2 Makefile
$ make top_dir=/etc/httpd
$ make install
```

I keep getting this error when I run make:

```
-bash: make: command not found
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Erm, obviously you haven't installed `make`.

On Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

On CentOS: `sudo yum install make gcc gcc-c++`

Comment: Not true - if that were the case he'd get that after the *first* make call, would he not?

Comment: He didn't specify _when_ he got the error. And I doubt that calling a command 2 times immediately after each other would produce `command not found` _only_ for the 2nd time.